# Difference between new HashMap(int) and guava Maps.newHashMapWithExpectedSize(int)

Tags: java, collections, guava

In Java, you can create a new `HashMap` to hold a specific number of items like so:

```
Map m = new HashMap(100);
```

Guava provides a `Maps.newHashMapWithExpectedSize(int)` method, which I would expect to simply call `HashMap(int)`. But it doesn't do this, instead it calculates its own capacity and uses that.

Why does `newHashMapWithExpectedSize` do its own thing, and why would I want to use it over calling `new HashMap(int)` directly?

Comment: My answer covers this, but the fundamental issue here is that the JDK API is bad because it doesn't size the `HashMap` "to hold a specific number of items" like you'd expect it would. Instead it sizes it to hold 75% of the number you specify.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you read the method's [Javadoc](https://guava.dev/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#newHashMapWithExpectedSize-int-)?

> Creates a `HashMap` instance, with a high enough "initial capacity" that it should hold `expectedSize` elements without growth.

Note that the `new HashMap(int)` constructor's "initial size" parameter specifies the initial size of the *hash table* that entries are stored in, which is basically an implementation detail that you shouldn't have to care about. The hash table will resize when it exceeds the map's *load factor* (which defaults to 0.75), which means that if you specify an initial capacity of 16 and then add 16 entries to the map, the hash table will almost certainly be resized.

With Guava's method, if you specify an *expected size* of 16 and then add 16 entries, the hash table should *not* resize.

Comment: Nope, you're example won't do this. The standard library will round the size up to 16 (the next power of 2) and filling it with 10 items will not exceed the threshold to extend the size. However if you have an expected size of 13 and fill it with 13 it will.

Comment: Thanks, fixed the specific example to use 16. For arbitrary sizes, it's still generally true that the table may resize if you specify an initial capacity that's equal to the number of entries you want to add.

Answer (score 3):

The HashMap constructor argument is the capacity of the map, i.e. the number of buckets.

So, if you pass 10 as argument, and store 8 keys in the map, the rehash threshold (75% by default) will be reached and the map will rehash.

On the other hand, the argument passed to newHashMapWithExpectedSize() is the expected size of the map. So if you pass 10, Guava will create a map with enough buckets to make sure the map doesn't rehash when inserting 10 elements: at least 14 buckets.

Comment: A `HashMap` uses the next power of two as its capacity. So if you set `initialCapacity` to 10, the real capacity will be 16. Factoring that by 0.75 results a total of 12 entries without resizing.

Comment: @Bubletan: This is true, but A) it's an implementation detail that's completely unspecified by the API, and B) it doesn't change the fact that for many possible values of `initialCapacity`, the table will have to be resized and rehashed in order to add that many entries.

Comment: @ColinD agreed, there is no way of knowing the actual initial capacity from the javadoc without reading the code. It is actually misleading in some places.

Answer (score 0):

Guava just multiplies the size passed by 2 (in a safe way) and calls the regular hashmap constructor. This makes it more sparse so there are less collisions while hashing.

The javadoc on the capacity calculation mentions that it calculates a value for the capacity so that the hashmap is between 25% and 50% full, which is far away from the threshold which would trigger a resizing.

The standard library rounds the expected size up to the nearest power of 2 and allocates that as the size and then sets the threshold for resizing to 75%. If we would randomly ask for sizes, the standard library would resize in 50% of cases.

If avoiding the threshold would be the only consideration, multiplying with 1.34  would be enough to have enough space to avoid resizing on filling it with the expected size of elements.

It looks like the typical speed vs space tradeof and the Google engineers being more speed freaks and the Sun/Oracle engineers more space nuts.

Comment: Nope.  If you call `new HashMap(n)` and then put n entries in, the hash table will get resized because it's not big enough by the JDK's definition; Guava's just compensating for that.

Comment: Yeah, as Louis said, the hash table will end up approximately the same size regardless of which method you use to construct the `Map`, so there shouldn't be any significant space different. The only difference is whether or not the hash table will have to be resized before all the entries you want to add can be added.

Comment: yep, you're right. It allocates the size rounded up to the next power of 2 and then set the normal loadfactor of 75%, which would get triggered when filling it with size items (if size is close enough to the rounded up number, or in about 50% of cases). I was under the mistaken belief that the standard library compensated for this. Still the number 2 is rather arbitrary, so I still believe the sparsity plays a role there too.